# Accessing session data from a layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

In my ASP.NET MVC solution I have a number of services.

One of them, SessionService, is used to access the currently selected region and time span.

I want to display those in a layout used to decorate views. What is the best design approach to access those values which are stored in the SessionService?

Right now I'm thinking about using calling a ChildAction from the layout which in turn calls the session service:

```
_Layout -> aController.ChildAction() -> SessionService.GetRegion()
```

Is it a good approach or can you recommend anything better?

UPDATE 1:
Other options for passing the values that are possible:

- via ViewBag
- via ViewModels

However the drawback for these options is the fact that it would be necessary to populate them in each and every action method which would lead to duplication of code (which could be mitigated by means of a filter, but again this will require decorating controllers with the filter).

UPDATE 2 (born in the discussion with O:rvar below):

Another option is to create a base controller which will be populating ViewBag properties upon creation. All other controllers should derive from it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access you session data in the view with the following code:

```
var region = @Session["Region"].ToString();
```

Or you could call the controller method as you mentioned with an ajax call and get the session data that way. Using the childaction approach is also a fine way of accomplishing what you want.

Comment: Thank you, Örvar. Right, I can access session data directly from the view. However from the point of view of testability, dependency injection and all the other best practices, I provide access to session data via SessionService:ISessionService and I don't want views to have direct access to it.

Comment: Ok, have you thought about getting the session data in the controller and populate a viewmodel that you then pass to the view?

Comment: Yes, i thought about passing the values via View Models or ViewBag - added an update to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Are your thoughts to get the session value by a click of a button or by some other event?

Comment: No, just along with navigating from page to page (each of them sharing a common layout which displays those region / timespan values).

Comment: I think perhaps that you are overcooking this, but then again I dont know 100% your requirements. Viewbags and viewmodels are intended to provide the view with data. And as the web is stateless you need to populate your view with data. You could create a seperate wrapper helper method that is called inside your controller to get the session data that then populates your viewmodel/viewbag for less duplication of code..

Comment: Thank you, Orvar. OK, probably not a wrapper which anyway needs to be called explicitly, but there is another option - to create a base controller which will be populating ViewBag properties with the values when created. All controllers need to derive from it.